# Specifying Maven dependencies in build.gradle doesn't work

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-management

I tried to add a Maven dependency to my project, which uses Gradle, by adding these lines to the build.gradle file in Android Studio:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:2.0'
}
```

The project seems to compile well, but there's no way to reference Roboguice classes inside my project's code. I feel like I'm missing something, namely, how does Gradle download the dependency and where will it store it? How should I fix my project?

Comment: You're saying your code is compiling well, but what do you mean by "but there's no way to reference Roboguice classes inside my project's code."?

Comment: Now I got it. you can't reference them from android studio?

Comment: After you change your dependencies in build.gradle, you have to re-import it into Studio. Or you have to go in the settings under Gradle and make sure auto-import is enabled for your project.

Comment: @Xav, Thanks for your answer. The solution that lukas proposed has done the job for me. Is there any chance that the Android Studio will handle this kind of things automatically in the future?

Comment: @Xav Auto-import does not seem to work, and gradle clean && gradle build not every time. Is there another task to run that avoid to close/open the project ? Thanks!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using the command line, in the root of your project, run :
`./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build`

Then recompile your project in studio and you should see your new dependencies.

**EDIT:** At the time of the answer, Android studio didn't propose the "Gradle sync" button. It now does, so rather than using the command line, you can hit the button, and it will basically run `./gradlew clean && ./gradlew build` for you.

Anyway, it's always good to know how to do it in command line :)

The name of the button is: **Sync Project with Gradle Files**
See the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: '.' refers to your current folder.

Comment: @lukas I am using Android Studio 0.4.6 and Gradle wrapper 0.10. I was working on the project for a while but suddenly a dependency cannot be found any more. You suggestion does not work for me.

Comment: @lukas, on Windows you don't need `./`, just `gradlew clean && gradlew build`

Answer (score 8):

On Android Studio I just press the **Sync Project with Gradle File** button, left of the **AVD Manager** did the job. No restart, no `./gradlew clean` or `./gradlew build`.

You can also navigate through **Tools-->Android-->Sync Project with Gradle File**.

Comment: This is the best answer,  as it doesn't require any command line usage and works within Android Studio (that WAS the OP's question, wasn't it?).

Comment: The OP didn't state requirements that he can't use command line. Understanding the command line tools is a good thing, because if you limit yourself to only fixing things in Android Studio, you're limiting yourself to what the UI supplies you when there's many more tools to use

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem. I tried all solutions suggested without success. Then I simply closed and opened again Android Studio and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here worked for me. What did work was **File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...**

This is an extremely annoying bug, that happens way more often that it should. The build tools should not be a hindrance to development.

Answer (score -2):

go to intellij preferences and enable gradle auto import dependencies

Comment: please be more specific with your answers.