# Using a maven library (android-times-square) with android studio 0.3.1

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I tried adding the library via `File --> Project Structure --> Modules --> Add Maven dependency` and selecting the `android-times-square:1.0.3` from the list shown. While it gets added I can't use it in my project.I have tried adding  `compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.0.3'` to my `build.gradle`

Also followed the two links below but none of them seem to make the library project/module available in my application module

[Specifying Maven dependencies in build.gradle doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16840982/specifying-maven-dependencies-in-build-gradle-doesnt-work)

[How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio)